# Does the HockeyApp Jenkins plug-in work for Android?

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp

I'd like to be able to upload my Android application binaries from Jenkins to HockeyApp automatically, but I'm not clear on if this is possible.

I see there's a published Jenkins plug-in:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HockeyApp+Plugin

Just not sure if it works for Android. It looks like the API specifically calls for an "ipa", however, on Hockeyapp's site, they say you can stick a .apk in there. Anybody tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works.

The [HockeyApp API](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-upload-new-apps) accepts either a .apk or .ipa file in the `ipa` parameter, which the Jenkins plugin uses. Furthermore, the `dsym` parameter accepts dSYM symbols from iOS, or a ProGuard mapping.txt file for Android.

As of plugin version 1.0.4, the UI and documentation has been updated to clarify that iOS, Mac OS X and Android apps are all supported via the same plugin.

Comment: Maybe consider updating the wiki entry for it too: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hockeyapp+Plugin

Comment: @anuron That's the wrong page. Check out https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HockeyApp+Plugin (note the capital A in HockeyApp). The Jenkins wiki has cached the old version which was renamed, for some reason.